# How to identify if textbox have more than one comma?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I think my question is simple.
I just need a little character check when I click in one button. If such textbox have more than one comma, I want a message: "Error. Please insert just one comma in the box."
I was searching but have not found anything like this. Can someone help me? Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Don't say "wrong validation". That will just confuse users, who likely don't know what validation means.

Comment: `bool hascomma = "no comma here".Count(a => a == ',') > 1;` will return false (this is using LINQ)

Comment: Although this problem CAN be solved using the counting method in the linked (and previously marked duplicate) Q&A, the test for "more than one" has a more efficient solution than counting them all.

Comment: IndexOf and LastIndexOf worked great for me, but I will take a look in another methods for future references. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502488/how-to-identify-if-a-string-contains-more-than-one-instance-of-a-specific-charac):

You can compare IndexOf to LastIndexOf to check if there is more than one specific character in a string without explicit counting:

```
var s = "12121.23.2";
var ch = '.';
if (s.IndexOf(ch) != s.LastIndexOf(ch)) {
    ...
}
```

In your case:

```
var s = "Comma, another comma, something.";
var ch = ',';
if (s.IndexOf(ch) != s.LastIndexOf(ch)) {
    ...
}
```

You can set a boolean when you check if there is a another comma in the string (Textbox.Text).

As listed above here is another [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-string) concerning your question.

As stated in the comments, you can use `.Count()`. Look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391481/number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string) for more.

Comment: @GrantWinney Thank you very much for your feedback. I tried to also link some more posts with other solutions as well.

Comment: Worked very well using this method. Thank you :)

Comment: @Hypister you are welcome. If you take a look at the other posts, there are better and cleaner ways of doing this; as some people pointed out in the comments.

Comment: @EliteGamer yep, I'm taking a look in other comments to compare solutions. See ya friend!