# How do I disable dropdown if populated when the page loads

Tags: .net, razor, dropdownlistfor

This drop down list is sometimes populated based on a search result.  When the fields is populated, it needs to be disabled, so that the selection cannot be changed.  But when the page is loaded without a result populating the field, it needs to be active.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOptions, new SelectList(this.Model.Options, "Key", "Value"), "Select...", new { @id = "ddlOption" + this.ViewBag.TabId, tabindex = 5001 })
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can optionally build the htmlAttributes parameter to include `disabled` or you would use javascript to enable/disable it

Include disabled attribute when need to and leave it out when needs to be enabled

```
// Conditional check for list size, if populated, then
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOptions, new SelectList(this.Model.Options, "Key", "Value"), "Select...", new { @id = "ddlOption" + this.ViewBag.TabId, tabindex = 5001, disabled = true })
// else, your original code
```

javascript version

```
// The placeholder is one of the default options, so length at least equals to 1
if (document.getElementById('ddlOption').children.length > 1) {
  document.getElementById('ddlOption').disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Vincent's solutions, here are other ways to accomplish enabling/disabling a control based on a condition.

The quickest solution is the first option below, using the `ExpandoObject` to add on the `disabled` attribute when the condition is met. The last option below, the custom Select Tag Helper, provides a cleaner implementation of a `<select>` tag that requires some processing.

**All that matters is the presence of the disabled attribute**

Note the following from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#javascript), stated in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66304836/5535143):

> All that matters is that if the [disabled] attribute is present at all, *regardless of its actual value*, its value is considered to be true. The absence of the attribute means its value is false.

**Use ExpandoObject to add `disabled` attribute**

```
@{
    dynamic htmlAttributes = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    htmlAttributes.id = "ddlOption" + this.ViewData["TabId"];
    htmlAttributes.tabindex = 5001;
    htmlAttributes.title = "Options";
    if (this.Model.Options.Count() > 1) { htmlAttributes.disabled = "disabled"; }
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOptions,
new SelectList(this.Model.Options, "Key", "Value"),
"Select...",
(object)htmlAttributes)
```

**Custom HTML Helper chained to DropDownListFor**

See this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75975981/enable-disable-controls-on-a-razor-web-page-using-asp-net-7-extension-methods/75977572#75977572). The custom HTML Helper allows for a cleaner implementation of C#/Razor syntax in your Razor page. The code below uses a custom HTML Helper named `.DisableIfFilled(this.Model.Options.Count())` that takes one parameter.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedOptions,
    new SelectList(this.Model.Options, "Text", "Value"),
    "Select...",
    new { @id = "ddlOption" + this.ViewData["TabId"], tabindex = 5001, title="Options" }).DisableIfFilled(this.Model.Options.Count())
```

DisableHtmlControlExtension.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;

namespace WebApplication1.Helpers
{
    public static class DisableHtmlControlExtension
    {
        public static IHtmlContent DisableIfFilled(
            this IHtmlContent htmlContent, int numOfOptions)
        {
            if (numOfOptions > 1)
            {
                StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                htmlContent.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
                string html = writer.ToString();

                const string disabled = "\"disabled\"";
                html = html.Insert(html.IndexOf(">",
                  StringComparison.Ordinal), " disabled= " + disabled);
                return new HtmlString(html);
            }

            return htmlContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following to the Razor page:

```
@using WebApplication1.Helpers
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

**Custom Select Tag Helper**

Instead of the `DropDownListFor` HTML Helper, the Select Tag Helper provides clearer readability for `<select>` tag output.

```
 <select asp-for="SelectedOptions" asp-items="@this.Model.Options"
        class="ctrl" tabindex=5001 title="Options" disableif>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
</select>
```

DisableIfSelectTagHelper.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace WebApplication1.Helpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("select", Attributes = "disableif")]
    public class DisableIfSelectTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            // https://rion.io/2017/04/27/extending-tag-helpers-in-asp-net-core-applications/
            base.Process(context, output);

            string content = output.PostContent.GetContent();
            // Process only if more than on one instance of the
            // '<option>' tag exists.
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502488/how-to-identify-if-a-string-contains-more-than-one-instance-of-a-specific-charac
            if (content.IndexOf("<option") != content.LastIndexOf("<option"))
            {
                output.Attributes.Add("disabled", null);
            }
            // Remove custom 'disableif' attribute that's used
            // to trigger the tag helper.
            TagHelperAttribute attr = output.Attributes.First(t => t.Name == "disableif");
            output.Attributes.Remove(attr);
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following to the Razor page:

```
@using WebApplication1.Helpers
@addTagHelper WebApplication1.Helpers.DisableIfSelectTagHelper, WebApplication1
```